# Installing TensorFlow Lite dependencies and OpenCV

Tags: pi-4

[image]

I am getting this error while running this command "bash get_pi_requirements.sh" to Install TensorFlow Lite dependencies and OpenCV for my object detection project. What could be the issue and any possible solution?

[ error: Command "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.1/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.1/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.1/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.1/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/home/dksgd2sub/tflite1/tflite1-env/include -I/usr/include/python3.11 -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.1/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.1/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.1/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-aarch64-3.1/numpy/core/src/npymath -c build/src.linux-aarch64-3.1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/build/src.linux-aarch64-3.1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-311/build/src.linux-aarch64-3.1/numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.o.d" failed with exit status 1
[end of output]

```
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: legacy-install-failure
  
  × Encountered error while trying to install package.
  ╰─> numpy
  
  note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
  hint: See above for output from the failure.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
]

Comment: Yea I've modified the post